# How to add wait time after a statement before execution of next statement in unix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, wait

In Unix, i have a code similar to the following

```
find /dir -name "filename*" -type f -print | xargs rm

case "$?" in
     "0") status="SUCCESS";;
      *) status=FAILED";;
esac
```

It has been returning FAILED and i think it is because the case statement is executed before the files are deleted completed. Perhaps if i add some wait time after the first statement i can be sure that the file is completely deleted. IF that is the case, then how to add some wait time like 60 seconds in the script?

EDIT: I should mention that the files are being deleted, and yet the exit status is not zero.

Comment: I think the command `sleep 60` might be helpful.

Comment: I was afraid of using sleep may cause problems in subsequent executions. If i have a LOT of files, then it is difficult to calculate how much time to be added

Comment: After using sleep and the specified time, does the script continue from the next statement or is there a chance that the program might be suspended entirely?

Comment: `find /dir -name "filename*" -type f -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is problematic if there are oddly named files that match your filespec.  If you pipe the output of find to xargs, you'll have the time-honoured [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp2]$ touch $'one\ntwo.txt' "three four.txt"
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp2]$ find . -name "*txt" -type f -print | xargs rm
rm: ./three: No such file or directory
rm: four.txt: No such file or directory
rm: ./one: No such file or directory
rm: two.txt: No such file or directory
```

Why not just handle your `rm` directly within `find`?

```
find /dir -name "filename*" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

To test your results, you can either grab `$?`:

```
find /dir -name "filename*" -type f -exec rm {} \;
result=$?
case "$result" in
etc, etc
```

(I put `$?` in a variable in case it would be useful to re-use it later, or if other commands need to run between `find` and where its return value is evaluated.)

Or you can just test for success directly:

```
if find /dir -name "filename*" -type f -exec rm {} \;
then
    echo "SUCCESS!"
else
    echo "FAIL!"
fi
```

**UPDATE:**

Per comments...  If you don't have to recurse through subdirectories, then a for loop is probably sufficient.

```
for file in *.txt; do
  if ! rm "$file"; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to remove $file" >&2
  fi
done
```

Or if you don't need the granularity of generating errors on individual files:

```
rm *.txt || echo "ERROR" >&2
```

I don't think I can make it any smaller.  :-P

Comment: I guess that would've been simpler. In this case however, 1. The file names only contain letters numbers and underscore and no other special characters, not even blank spaces. 2. All files are in the specified directory and no subdirectories. So i see no reason why xargs would fail.

The problem was that, the contents of the folder keep changing, and at times there's no files at all. so then, xargs fails without operands and returns 123 exit status.

Comment: If you don't have to traverse a directory, then a for loop is sufficient.  `for file in *.txt; do rm "$file"; done`.  Do try to avoid the Parsing LS problem.  Even if (or perhaps because) it only sometimes bites you in the ass, it's a bad habit to get in to.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, I'm assuming "similar to the following" includes having *both* quotes around the `FAILED` string literal. If not, you should probably fix that first.

It's *very* unlikely that the `case` starts before the previous processes finish. Short of using `&` to run something in the background, that's just not the UNIX way :-)

The first thing you should do is replace the `case` statement with:

```
rc=$?
case $rc in
    0) status="SUCCESS";;
    *) status="FAILED"; echo rc=$rc;;
esac
```

to see what the return code actually is. Then look up `man xargs` (`$?` is always the exit code of the last thing in the pipeline) which shows you the possible values and their likely causes. For example:

```
EXIT STATUS
    xargs exits with the following status:
         0 if it succeeds
       123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
       124 if the command exited with status 255
       125 if the command is killed by a signal
       126 if the command cannot be run
       127 if the command is not found
         1 if some other error occurred.
    Exit codes greater than 128 are used by the shell to indicate
    that a program died due to a fatal signal.
```

Comment: Yes there are double quotes on FAILED sorry for the typo.

Comment: btw, IS there a difference in using "0" and 0 for the case statement?

Comment: @Jay, Shouldn't be - `$?` is a numeric variable that always exists so you don't need to wrap it in a string at all. Based on a test I just performed, it appears not to matter.

Comment: Just checked. It doesnt return anything. rc value is blank.

Comment: I find that somewhat ... perplexing. Are you using `bash`? If so, `$?` should always have a value.

Comment: When i ran the script, the files WERE deleted but no exit status was given. Then i ran it again, with no files to delete, the exit status  is 123 and status result was FAILED